# Find the limit of a sequence with factorial in it

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, factorial

I would like to know to find the limit of this sequence:

$${n^n\over n!}$$

It diverges, I know, but I don't know how to come to this conclusion.

Comment: I'm afraid Mathematics StackExchange was never meant to replace textbooks.

Comment: You can see that the sequence just increases!! Compare each term in the product of $n!$ with $n.$

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$n^n = \underbrace{ n \cdot n \cdots n}_{n \text{ factors}}$

while

$n! = \underbrace{ 1 \cdot 2 \cdots n}_{n \text{ factors}}$

Therefore $$\frac{n^n}{n!} = \frac{n}{1}\cdot \frac{n}{2} \cdots \frac{n}{n} > \frac{n}{1} = n \to \infty$$

as $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for integer $n$,
$$\frac{n^n}{n!}=\frac{n\cdot n\cdot n\cdot...\cdot n}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot...\cdot n}$$
and
$$\frac{n\cdot n\cdot n\cdot...\cdot n}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot...\cdot n}\ge \frac{n\cdot n\cdot n\cdot...\cdot n}{1\cdot n\cdot n\cdot...\cdot n}=n$$
so
$$\frac{n^n}{n!}\ge n$$
and since the sequence $\{n\}$ diverges, the sequence 
$$\bigg\{\frac{n^n}{n!}\bigg \}$$
also diverges.

Comment: For positive integers $n$.